# How to create a new terminal session and execute multiple commands

Tags: bash

I'm looking for a way to automate the start-up of my development environment. I have three virtual machines that have to be started, then have to `ssh` to each of them and open VPN on them.

So far I've gotten them to start and managed to ssh to them:

```
#!/bin/sh 
virsh start virtual_1
virsh start virtual_2
virsh start virtual_3
sleep 2m

gnome-terminal --title "virtual_3: server" -x ssh root@192.168.1.132 &
gnome-terminal --title "virtual_2: 11.100" -x ssh root@192.168.11.100 &
gnome-terminal --title "virtual_1: 12.100" -x ssh root@192.168.12.100 &
```

How do I execute an additional command in each of the terminals which starts openvpn?

For simplicity I'm trying to `echo 1` in each terminal instead of starting VPN.

I've found that multiple commands on terminal start can be run like:

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "cmd1; cmd2"
```

So for one terminal to keep it simple I changed:

```
gnome-terminal --title "virtual_3: server" -x ssh root@192.168.1.132 &
```

to:

```
gnome-terminal --title "virtual_3: server" -x bash -c "ssh root@192.168.1.132 ; echo 1" &
```

But `1` wasn't printed in the terminal of virtual_3.
Then I thought, maybe the command is being executed too quickly, before the terminal is ready, so I tried adding `&&`:

```
gnome-terminal --title "virtual_3: server" -x bash -c "ssh root@192.168.1.132 &&; echo 1" &
```

But that gave no result either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, if you run

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "cmd1; cmd2"
```

you get `bash` to execute `cmd1` and `cmd2`. It doesn't first execute `cmd1` and then give `cmd2` to its result. `ssh` is a program run in the terminal and your `cmd2` won't be executed until that is finished.

So you need to run `ssh` and tell *that* to execute your command.

You can do so by:

```
ssh user@address "command_to_execute"
```

However, `ssh` exits after the command is finished. As you can see in "[With ssh, how can you run a command on the remote machine without exiting?](https://superuser.com/a/261619/105764)", you can execute `ssh` with the `-t` option so it doesn't quit:

```
ssh -t user@address "command_to_execute"
```

So your command in the end becomes:

```
gnome-terminal --title "virtual_3: server" -x bash -c "ssh -t root@192.168.1.132 'echo 1'"
```

---

You are right, giving `-t` alone is not enough (although necessary). `-t` allocates buffer for the `tty` but doesn't execute bash for you. From the manual of `ssh`:

> -t  **Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine**, which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.
>
> If `command` is specified, it is executed on the remote host **instead of a login shell.**

So what you need is, to execute bash your self. Therefore:

```
ssh -t user@address "command_to_execute; bash"
```

Comment: Tnx for the reply, however it didn't work it just opens and closes immediately . Here is what I tried directly from the console to see whats it outputting (since it closes to fast).

input: ssh root@192.168.1.132 'echo 1'
output: 1

input: ssh -t root@192.168.1.132 'echo 1' 
output: 1
        Connection to 192.168.1.132 closed.